# How do I shorten a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go about shortening a number like 1,000 into 1k, 1,000,000 into 1m, and so on in Python 3.X?

I have been experimenting with this line of code:

```py
print("{:,}".format(1000)) # returns 1,000
```

I get errors when I place anything besides a comma there.

Comment: Short version: There's no built-in for this, so you either roll your own, or find an existing third party library that does it for you.

Comment: https://python-humanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @John Specifically [`humanize.number.metric()`](https://python-humanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/number/#humanize.number.metric)?